# Reset or backup from a blockchain possible?

Tags: blockchain, altcoin, bitcoin-core-development, altcoin-development, wallet-development

i have a coin for my own interests.
With this i will learn how works all.

So i have install the daemon on a vps
All works fine.

Mining works. And the first 300 blocks i have created.

Now i will back to block 100 or 200.
But i don't know how?

It is only one node (1vps) and 1 windows wallet.

Is it enough to delete all files and directorys except the coin.conf and wallet.dat on the vps and in windows?

Or how i can back to block 200?

Many thanks
Mark

Answer (score 1):

> `invalidateblock "blockhash"`
>
> > Permanently marks a block as invalid, as if it violated a consensus rule.
> >
> > Arguments:
> >
> > 1. "blockhash"   (string, required) the hash of the block to mark as invalid

Don't delete the blocks manually, you'll harm the database.

Comment: Thanks MCCCS for your reply. Understand I correct this works for me when i input the hash from block 201? Then I'm at block 200?

Comment: Yes, that's how it works.

Comment: OK, thanks. And when I setup 2 vps then I must insert this in all XXX-cli or only by one? And restart number 2?

Comment: You should do that for both.